# Anybody else get this error from knn.impute?

Tags: r

I am not sure why but I am getting the following error when applying knn.impute:

```
Error in storage.mode(use.data) <- "double" : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

I don`t see anything wrong with the data.

Data:

```
library(bnstruct)
data(iris)
data <- iris[, 1:4]
data <- prodNA(iris, noNA = 0.2) # generate random missing data
knn.impute(data, k = 10, cat.var = 1:ncol(data),
           to.impute = 1:nrow(data), using = 1:nrow(data))

str(data)

'data.frame':   150 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
```

Comment: Can confirm.  I get the same error using mtcars.  `m <- subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg, cyl, wt)); m[1:10,]$mpg <- NA; knn.impute(m, k = 4)`

Comment: This alternate function works for me.  `library(DMwR); m <- subset(mtcars, select = c(mpg, cyl, wt)); m[1:10,]$mpg <- NA; knnImputation(m, k = 4)`

Comment: Thanks I have it working using the `DMwR` data. However I get an error when using it with the following: `data <- subset(data, select = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",  "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))
x <- knnImputation(data, k = 3)`

Comment: `data <- subset(data, select = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width",  "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width"))
data$nrow <- seq(from = 1, to = nrow(data))
x <- knnImputation(data, k = 10)` seems to solve that previous issue I was having.

Comment: `bnstruct::knn.impute` is documented to accept a dataframe as input, but in fact it requires a matrix.

Comment: @user2554330 is correct, the documentation of `bnstruct::knn.impute` is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, `bnstruct::knn.impute` requires a numerical matrix, and it will not work with a dataframe. It will work with

```
data <- iris[, 1:4]
data <- prodNA(data, noNA = 0.2)
knn.impute(as.matrix(data), k = 10, cat.var = 1:ncol(data),
           to.impute = 1:nrow(data), using = 1:nrow(data))
```

The documentation is wrong, sorry for that, I'm fixing it as soon as possible.

EDIT: the correct documentation has been updated in the github repo.